# How to handle Date collected from HTML and saving in MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, date, date-formatting

I'm going mad trying to handle a Date collected from an HTML form. I'm using Spring 4 for the back-end and Mongodb for the persistence.

My problem is how the date is displayed in Mongo. I'd like to get the following format: dd-MM-yyyy. I think I understand that Mongo uses ISO format as default (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ) but when I'm trying to insert a new document, after filling a form, the Date is saved as a number value, so my questions are:

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is possible to save the Date in dd-MM-yyyy format keeping dateOfBirth of Date type?
3. If it's not, how can I  ave the Date in the standard ISO format?

**Customer class** (I changed the setter method in order to parse the Date binded by the form)

```
@Document
public class Customer implements UserDetails {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String role;

    public Customer() { }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, Date dateOfBirth, String username,
            String email, String password, String role) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    //getters, setters, etc.

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return this.dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        try {
            this.dateOfBirth = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(dateOfBirth);
        } 
        catch (ParseException e) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

**registration.html**

```
<div class="form">
    <h2>Registration</h2>
    <form th:action="@{/registration}" method="POST"
        th:object="${customer}">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="firstName"
            th:field="*{firstName}" /> <input type="text" placeholder="Cognome"
            name="lastName" th:field="*{lastName}" /> <input type="date"
            name="dateOfBirth" th:field="*{dateOfBirth}" /> <input type="text"
            placeholder="Username" name="username" th:field="*{username}" /> <input
            type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" th:field="*{email}" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"
            th:field="*{password}" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The controller which is mapped with "/registration" value uses DAO to insert the new Customer.

This is the result:

[image: MongoDB result]

Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no problems as I see them, but you need some explanation.

> Why is this happening?

The value you see is still a Date, its just being displayed in long equivalent in the viewer that you are using.

Check the same document through Mongo shell you should see the date in ISO format, but internally it is saved in long value.

> Is possible to save the Date in dd-MM-yyyy format keeping dateOfBirth
>   of Date type?

`dd-MM-yyyy` is date format and if you want to store that you have to change the date type to string. Not recommended.

> If it's not, how can I ave the Date in the standard ISO format?

You don't save date with any format. Its internal representation is a long value. First point should answer about the format part.

Comment: I tried to display the date value saved in the db into a view and day, month and year doesn't matches. For example if I insert 19 06 1990 the value shown is Fri Nov 10 00:00:00 CET 24. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure where it is going wrong. First thing, do you see the right value in db ?

Comment: Seems like the value from frontend is not correct. Can you add a debug point in  `setDateOfBirth` method and verify the value you see ?

Comment: Fixed! I was using wrong SimpleDateFormat. The correct one is yyyy-MM-dd. Thanks again!